# UICollectionViewCell and Autolayout scaling

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've built a vanilla UICollectionView that uses cells that are the full size of my screen...

The ViewCells I am using are defined in IB with dimensions of 320x568, and I have added auto layout constraints that should allow these to scale down when the window size changes.

**Is there a way to have a normal collection view flow layout detect changes in the available window (in-call bar, 3.5 inch screen, etc.), and update the viewcell default sizes so that they match the available real estate, or is this going to require customized code to listen for the change in resolution? If so, what is the method I need to implement to capture this change in window size?**

Answer (score 1):

This might work :

Subclass a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override the method (shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange) like this :

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    [self invalidateLayout];
    return YES;
}
```

This will force a refresh of the layout on bounds changes of the collectionView. (a rotation for example).

also you'll have to implement the following method of UICollectionViewDelegate :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.collectionView.bounds.size;
}
```

Now if you have good constraints on you collectionsView, it's frame should be updated on window changes and result in a layout update.

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not result in updates to the actual itemsize, so even though the layout updates, the cells are not scaled down when needed.

Comment: I edited my answer. Tested that on a small project, it seems to work.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how does this resolve the issue of setting  item size so that it remains "full screen", and handles modifications to the status bar height? Invalidate Layout simply tells the runtime that it should recalculate things, but I don't see how you're indicating a new itemsize based on available screen constraints.

Comment: Also, all I did was giving you a way to keep items at the size of your collectionView at anytime. Now you'll have to put the right constraints on it